# OpenSearch Index Lifecycle management

Tags: indexing, opensearch

What is the ilm policy for a opensearch index which requires only delete 30 days data without deleting the index.

I see the policies for Index deletion not the data inside the index.

is this possible without deleting the index? please help me ?

Comment: check this: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/document-apis/delete-by-query/